# Facebook Sharing debugger not picking up OG tags

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph, facebook-debugger

Whenever I put https://enginity.be/ into [the Facebook debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/), it doesn't display the image or description into the share box, and it informs me those og tags are missing.

However, when you look at the source code of the website, you'll see the needed og tags are clearly there.

What's going wrong?

Comment: "Can't validate SSL Certificate"...that is what the debugger says

Comment: You’re missing an intermediate certificate. https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html#hostname=https://enginity.be/

Comment: Thanks guys, I'll take a look into it!